# i wish to know what does the following pointer equating do?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the code below:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

node* ptr1 = new node;
node* ptr2 = new node;
node* ptr3 = new node;

ptr1->data = 1;
ptr1->next = ptr2;

ptr2->data = 2;
ptr2->next = ptr3;

ptr3->data = 3;
ptr3->next = NULL;

*(ptr1) = *(ptr2);

node* temp;
temp = ptr1;

while (temp != NULL)
{
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

> 2 2 3

i.e the value at address of `ptr` should be now equal to the value at address of `ptr2` as `ptr1` and `ptr2` actually point to the data part of the node..(as i saw by printing the address values)

but the output is:

> 2 3

i expected my output because when i print `*(ptr2)`, (using `printf` and not `cout`; `cout` shows error), i get the output as:

> 2

Please someone explain what is happening.
what does `*ptr1 = *ptr2` do?

Comment: Because the `data` member isn't the only thing being copied when you blast the second structure over the first. There's another member in that structure. Think about what it contains. Paper, pencil/pen, boxes and arrows will come in real handy, btw.

Comment: Passing `*ptr2` to `printf` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
*(ptr1) = *(ptr2);
```

in this situation is equivalent to:

```
ptr1->data = ptr2->data
ptr1->next = ptr2->next
```

that is all members of your structure are reafected, so your `ptr1->next` no longer points to `ptr2` node but directly points to `ptr3`, which is why only 2 values are printed instead of 3

You went from this:

```
[ptr1]==>[ptr2]==>[ptr3]
```

to this:

```
[ptr2]==>[ptr3]
[ptr1]==>[ptr3]
```

Answer (score 2):

*(ptr1) = *(ptr2); copies the data and the next ptr spoiling the linked list.
You only want to copy the data.
So it should be

```
ptr1->data = ptr2->data
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
*(ptr1) = *(ptr2);
```

the object of the type `struct node` pointed to by the pointer `ptr2` is assigned to the object of the same type `struct node` pointed to by the pointer `ptr1`.

So as result you have

```
ptr1 -> { 2, ptr3 }
ptr2 -> { 2,  ptr3 }
ptr3 -> { 3, nullptr }
```

So in this loop that starts from `ptr1`

```
temp=ptr1;
while(temp!=NULL)
{

    cout<<temp->data<<" ";
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

there are displayed two objects poinetd to by `ptr1` (that in turn points to `ptr3`) and the object pointed to by `ptr3`.

The reference to `ptr2` in the object pointed to by the pointer `ptr1` is lost. Now the data member `next` of the object points directly to the object pointed to by the pointer `ptr3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptr1   ->    ptr2    ->     ptr3
 1            2              3
```

When *(ptr1) = *(ptr2) is done, the structure becomes as follows:

```
ptr1    ->     ptr3
 2              3

                ^
                |
                |
               ptr2
                2
```

Hope it is clear why it prints 23 now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
*(ptr1) = *(ptr2);
```

Here you are changing the underlying memory location of
`ptr1` to be exactly that of `ptr2`, which has the effect of iterate starting from `ptr2` (which is why the output is 2 3).

If you wanted the output to be `2 2 3`
you would have to change the *data* at ptr1:

```
ptr1->data = ptr2->data
```